# How to find which view is used from ng-view or ui-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating one plugins which will used in angularjs application.

But i have 2 queries :

1.How can i check that which one is used `'ng-view' ($routeProvider)` or `'ui-view' ($stateProvider)` by user in his/her application ??

2.I want to get `module name` which he/she has defined in main `app.js` so by using that default(already defined) module name i can apply my custom angular functionality on that module.

Thanks